# How to prove a space is a dual space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

How does one go about proving that a space is a dual space? The only thing I can think of is to prove that the space is isomorphic to a dual space. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: That won't do it. See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148926/quasi-reflexive-spaces-which-are-not-isometric-to-dual-spaces).

Comment: @DavidMitra I see.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is enough to show that the unit ball is compact with respect to some locally convex topology, that is weaker than the norm topology. See [this article](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11054/9075).

For example, if $X$ is a reflexive space with a basis, then the unit ball of $\mathscr B(X)$, the space of bounded linear operators on $X$, furnished with the weak operator topology is compact. This means that $\mathscr B(X)$ is a dual space. (Of course in this case it is not very difficult to identify the predual explicitly.)